# How to create an Organisation Structure in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: organization-profile

I need to create an Organisation Structure for my organisation in SharePoint 2013. The feature of the Organisation structure should be as follows:
Whenever an employee clicks to view his Organistaion Structure on Department as well as Organisation level he should be able view the hierarchy of his supervisors and sub-ordinates.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please provide a better description and detail what you have tried and how you think you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have User Profile Service Application up and running and synchronized with Active Directory (or any other Directory Service supported) you could implement MySite where you have Organizational Chart out of the box.

When implemented, it will reflect any changes in the Directory Service and doesn't need to be configured due to future organizational changes.

> ## Org Chart
>
> Displays an organization chart. The chart shows the user's position in the organization among management, peers, and direct reports. You can select other people from the chart to view their profiles.

Reference: [Overview of My Sites in SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382643.aspx)

Comment: Hi Benny, Thanks for your reply. I have a customised mysite in my organisation. How to activate/implement organisation chart there.I can't find an option.

Comment: @PriyankaRajput The org chart is hidden on your own about me page by default, but if you visit another member of your organization you will see it under their about me page